# Is there a protocol specify behavior about how to render the HTML

Tags: html, google-chrome, email, firefox, email-client

There is a snippet HTML

`<ol><li><p>XXX</p></li><li><p>XXX</p></li></ol>`

When rendered in browser, It looks like

1. XXX
2. XXX

When rendered in Foxmail(an email client), It looks like

1.

XXX

2.

XXX

**Why the behavior that Foxmail renders the p tag nested inside the li tag doesn't like browser?**

**Is there a protocol specify behavior about how to render the HTML?**

**Is this a peculiarly Foxmail problem?**

Comment: You have a `<p>` element nested inside an `<li>`. A paragraph tag (`<p>`) is a block level element, and by default it'll not render as inline or inline-block. Actually if you reuse the same exact HTML snippet inside the browser, it'd behave the same. You might want to apply styling to it to get around it.

Comment: @BumhanYu You'll have to explain that better because it behaves exactly as it should in the browser. I have not looked at email but it should behave the same way there.

Comment: Thanks. If this is a peculiarly Foxmail problem, I don't want to solve it by set the p tag as an inline element. I still want to checkout the protocol about how to render the HTML